# Entity Framework Relationships with Existing Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a project where I am taking an existing database and converting the stored procedures into an Entity Framework respository.  I am running into quite a few issues setting up the Entity relationships.  I am unable to alter the structure of the database so I have to find a solution within code.

Lets say I have a Clients Table and a Notes table.  Clients has a one to many relationship with Notes.

In Clients, I have a field called Client_Id(the primary key) , In the Notes table I have a Note_Id and a Account_ID.  The Clients.Client_Id maps to Notes.Account_Id.

Now, in tables that have the same key value I can just create a ICollection and Enity will create the relationship just fine. But since the names are different and there is no foreign keys to map how do I get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to configure these mappings using either Data Annotations or the Fluent API. Here's a sample of how you might do it using the annotations:

```
[Table("Clients")]
class Client 
{
  [Key]
  public int Client_Id {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes {get;set;}
}

[Table("Notes")]
class Note 
{
  [Key]
  public int Note_Id {get;set;}
  public int Account_Id {get;set;}
  [ForeignKey("Account_Id")]
  public virtual Client Client {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: The thing is , I don't want a foreign key - I would like just the base one to many relationship.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand ... when you say you don't want a foreign key, do you mean you don't want the foreign key property in your Note class?

Comment: After thinking about it -Foreign keys work beccause I can use the HasOptional vs the HasRequired.   I just wanted to ensure that while I had the actual relationship, I would not have to have a note in order to save a client.  I am also doing this in Fluent API - what would the syntax be in a POCO or mapping class?  Would it be the same as above? Or would I do this in the onmodelcreating method ?

Comment: This exactly answers the question, and is the correct answer - you should accept this answer. If you want clarification of how to do it using Fluent API as opposed to annotations, ask a separate question ... or better yet, find one of the dozen or so answers already out there on SO.